# Cannot open Service Control manager by service hosted in IIS with a locl account as user in the app pool

Tags: c#, iis, privileges, rights

I have a service hosted in IIS on a  windows 2016 standard server that uses System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices() to retrieve the running services. When I use a custom app pool with a local user account I get the error

`Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied`

the local account has the privileges to serve as a app pool user in IIS. When I switch to the default app pool with ApplicationPoolIdentity as the identity, the service runs fine.

Which privileges do i miss? ( I also added the user to the administrators group.

the server is a windows 2016 standard server and the code is writen in c#, .net 4.8

I tried to add the user to the administrator group.
in the local group policy editor added the IIS APPPOOL<App pool> to the following user rights assignments:

- Generate Sevurity audits
- log on as a service
- replace a process level token

which rights or privileges do i miss that the ApplicationPoolIdentity has.

Comment: could you set load user profile to true in the iis app pool advance setting. and instead of assigning group policy to the app pool user assign it to the user which you are using with iis app pool. if this will not work collect the process monitor logs

Comment: Hi,@JalpaPanchal I tried to set "load user profile" to true. no luck, same result. I will collect the process monitor logs. anything specific to look for?

Comment: you can try to find the failing request in the process monitor to see with which user it failing

Comment: I checked with the sysinternals proces monitor. I found no exceptions. For now I except that the app pool uses the ApplicationPoolIdentity as Identity. 
The additional information that I can share is in iis the application uses anonymous authentication as authentication method.

Comment: could try adding custom account in anonymous authentication  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSxtW.png)